# How to modify the mouse pointer icon dynamically

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, xlib

I'm trying to simulate mouse interaction in ubuntu.
Now, I can move the mouse pointer and create button press events using XLib but I would also like to display additional information near, or replacing, the mouse icon. I try to do this for any window.

I have tried to use the Xlib functions to modify the mouse pointer icon:

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay( 0 );
Window root = DefaultRootWindow( display );
char data[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... };
char dataM[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... };

Pixmap source = XCreatePixmapFromBitmapData( display, root, data, 16, 16, 1, 0, 1 );
Pixmap mask = XCreatePixmapFromBitmapData( display, root, dataM, 16, 16, 1, 0, 1 );

XColor fg_color, bg_color;
fg_color.red = 65000; fg_color.green = 60000; fg_color.blue = 30000; fg_color.flags = DoRed | DoGreen | DoBlue;
bg_color.red = 650; bg_color.green = 6000; bg_color.blue = 30000; bg_color.flags = DoRed | DoGreen | DoBlue;
Cursor c = XCreatePixmapCursor( display, source, mask, &fg_color, &bg_color, x, y );

XDefineCursor( display, root, c );
XFlush( display );
sleep(2);

// modify cursor's colors
fg_color.red = 10; fg_color.green = 60000; fg_color.blue = 60000;
ret = XRecolorCursor( display, c, &fg_color, &bg_color );
XDefineCursor( display, root, c );
XFlush( display );
XFreeCursor( display, c );
sleep(2);
```

but I see no modifications of the mouse pointer shape or color.

What did I miss in my code? Or do I need to use something else for Ubuntu 12.04 with unity?

Comment: You are setting the cursor of the root window. On most current desktops the root window is never seen, as the desktop application draws its own window over it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll try to find the desktop window.

Comment: If you are interested in the desktop window, I have *very* *old* code for this here: http://fopref.meinungsverstaerker.de/xmms-rootvis/ It might still be working.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll have a look at it this weekend